# Vert.x - how it deals with: proxy, connection restarts, transactions? Which websocket servers. browser it supports?

Tags: vert.x

Vert.x - how it deals with: proxy, connection restarts, transactions?
I also cannot find any table as for which websocket servers. browser it supports and how it falls into other transport than websocket depending on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Vert.x implements IO protocol stack for [SockJS](http://sockjs.org) Javascript library, it is a server. Your javascript code relies on SockJS library to choose proper protocol for communication with server (websockets or XHR or JSONP or SSE fallback), e.g.

```
Polling transports are used as a fallback for old browsers and hosts behind restrictive proxies.
```

Vert.x also has a built-in client to other websocket servers. Take a look at the [websockets documentation](http://vertx.io/core_manual_java.html#websockets)